# Ошибка UNIQUE constraint failed: albums.ID . Как можно исправить?

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, tkinter

```
class Child(tk.Toplevel):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(root)
        self.init_child()

    def init_child(self):
        BD()

        self.title('Доходы/Расходы')
        self.geometry('400x220+400+300')

        label_description = tk.Label(self, text='Описание: ')
        label_description.place(x=50, y=50)
        label_select = tk.Label(self, text='Доходы/Расходы: ')
        label_select.place(x=50, y=80)
        label_sum = tk.Label(self, text='Сумма: ')
        label_sum.place(x=50, y=110)


        self.entry_description = ttk.Entry(self)
        self.entry_description.place(x=200,y=50)
        self.entry_money = ttk.Entry(self)
        self.entry_money.place(x=200,y=110)

        self.combobox = ttk.Combobox(self, values=(u'Доходы',u'Расходы'),state='readonly')
        self.combobox.current(0)
        self.combobox.place(x=200,y=80)

        btn_add = tk.Button(self, text='Добавить', command = BD().add_item())
        btn_add.place(x=220, y=170)
        btn_add.bind('<Button-1>')

        btn_cancel = tk.Button(self, text='Отменить', command=lambda: self.destroy())
        btn_cancel.place(x=300, y=170)
        btn_cancel.bind('<Button-1>')


        self.grab_set()
        self.focus_set()



class BD:
    def create(self):
        conn = sqlite3.connect('finance.db')
        cursor = conn.cursor()

        cursor.execute("""CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS albums (ID integer primary key,
                                                              description text,
                                                              costs text,
                                                              total real)""")

        conn.commit()

    def add_item(self):
        conn = sqlite3.connect('finance.db')
        cursor=conn.cursor()
        cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO albums VALUES ( 1 , 'self.entry_description.get()', 'self.combobox.get()', 'self.entry_money.get()' )""")

    def delete_item(self):
        pass
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def add_item(self):
    cursor = sqlite3.connect('finance.db').cursor()
    cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO albums(description, costs, total) VALUES ('self.entry_description.get()', 'self.combobox.get()', 'self.entry_money.get()' )""")
```

Answer (score 0):

Каждый раз при вставке вы указываете идентификатор строки 1. При повторной вставке SQL начинает ругаться, что ID неуникален, т.е. в таблице уже есть строка с таким ID. Просто не заполняйте это поле при вставке - SQLite для полей `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` автоматически подставит свободное значение (в других СУБД для этого поля при создании таблицы еще нужно указать тип `AUTOINCREMENT`):

> On an INSERT, if the ROWID or INTEGER PRIMARY KEY column is not
>   explicitly given a value, then it will be filled automatically with an
>   unused integer, usually one more than the largest ROWID currently in
>   use. This is true regardless of whether or not the AUTOINCREMENT
>   keyword is used.

[Источник](https://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html)